# windows phone database - best way to access it

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am having database in my windows phone 8 application. And I wonder, what should be the "best" practise to access it.

In last application, I had class with static methods called "AccessingDatabse" and when I need to do something with it, I just called method like `AccessingDatabase.savePlayer(player)`. The advantage was easy access and simple handling of more requests (I had more threads accessing database) with this :

```
public static AutoResetEvent OperationOnDatabase = new AutoResetEvent(true);

public static RefreshMessages()
        {
            try
            {
                OperationOnDatabase.WaitOne();
                //dosomething
            }
            finally
            {
                OperationOnDatabase.Set();
            }
        }
```

Is there a better way?

I can have - for example - saved the Database Context in `MainViewModel` and access it with

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>().MyDatabase
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a better solution would be to allow access to your database through a formal repository and use a DI framework inject the repository in the code that requires it. This way you can coordinate easily and at the same time you won't have the hard dependency that you have when you are using static methods and it will increase testability of classes using the repository immensely.

If DI is too heavy for you, just inject the repository in the ctor manually (although this will result in reduced testability in some places).